# How the computer language calculate the interval between time?

Tags: time, binary, computer-science

I explain, is a concept question, all we know the computer works only with 0s and 1 internally, but my question is how the time is calculated? How the computer knows that 1 second really are 1 second only with binary 0s and 1s ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the main differences between analog circuits, and digital circuits, as you point out, is that i digital circuits the active elements tend to have discrete unambiguous values (`0` and `1`).

But the other main difference is that while analog circuits evolve continuously in time, digital circuits only make changes to their state at *discrete* time steps.

Ultimately, everything is analog. A memory cell in a digital circuit, has to be implemented using analog circuit design principles. What is done is that a circuit is created that only has two stable states, the `0` and the `1` state, and any other state is highly unstable and tends rapidly towards `0` or `1`. It's possible that the state will shift, but only in response to an impulse of a large magnitude from an external source, or at least that will be one of the main design goals.

To make the system even more reliable, the whole thing is synchronized using a clock pulse. That is, generally all of the circuit elements are stable except when the clock pulse signal arrives, then they update based on external signals, then they have some time to stabilize again, until the next clock pulse. The clock pulse is generated using something like a quartz crystal, which always generates extremely regular signals, because of physics and chemistry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_generator

One way to make the hardware faster is to make all the components stabilize reliably in a shorter amount of time. Then the clock pulse can be made faster and the whole computer can do more cycles in a shorter amount of time without compromising reliability. Indeed for a long time great advances in computer hardware followed this plan. (But ultimately, there are limits on how short the cycles really can be before no device can stabilize quickly enough.)

So, it's actually not a surprise that the computer can keep track of time using only `0`'s and `1`'s. At the most fundamental level the hardware is built around keeping track of time precisely.

Answer (score 0):

> System time is measured by a system clock, which is typically implemented as a simple count of the number of ticks that have transpired since some arbitrary starting date, called the epoch.
>   [...]
>   System time can be converted into calendar time, which is a form more suitable for human comprehension. For example, the Unix system time 1000000000 seconds since the beginning of the epoch translates into the calendar time 9 September 2001 01:46:40 UT.

See more ate the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time

EDIT: the conversion of the mentioned ticks to binary is straightforward, right?